# Apigee iOS SDK and SSKeychain

Tags: ios, apigee

I'm currently trying to make use of the Apigee SDK for iOS but I also have a need to use SSKeychain. Because the Apigee iOS already incorporates and uses this, I get a duplicate Symbol error when I try to include it in my project. Unfortunately the Apigee framework doesn't expose SSKeychain for me to access via the framework either (at least not that I can tell).

Does anyone know how I can make use of SSKeychain and the Apigee SDK? I thought about using the steps here http://atnan.com/blog/2012/01/12/avoiding-duplicate-symbol-errors-during-linking-by-removing-classes-from-static-libraries/ but I don't know if removing SSKeychain from the framework and then adding it to my project would have any side effects.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix for this has already been pushed to the Apigee iOS SDK repo. You can grab the latest from github.

Here's the relevant commit: https://github.com/apigee/apigee-ios-sdk/commit/a7bd83a8c17f53afb36e29bb251c81305944d61e